# Javascript - Parsing multiple formats from a csv file loop in an api request

Tags: csv, datetime, validation, format, papaparse

I'm trying to parse a csv file that may have different formats of dates,
one file can have for example: "Data di fatturazione: 23.10.2023"
another can have:  23.10.2023, another 23.10.23 and so on.

I need a way to loop when there is the parsing with papaparse and parse the date accordingly testing all the possibile formats.

Thank you!

I have tried this way, the "Data di fatturazione: " trim correctly, but other formats not work.

If I have only one item in the "possibileFormats" it work, but with other formats it give me invalid date and set to null.

```
  //Using PapaParse to parse the combination of first and second row (headers and header data) while keeping the standard
      const possibleFormats = ["yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
      //@ts-ignore
      const parsed = Papa.parse(fs.readFileSync(file.filepath, "utf-8"), {
        header: true,
        complete: (results) => {
          return results;
        },
        transformHeader: (h: any) => {
          //Header normalization
          const normalizedHeader = ParserNormalizer.transformHeader(
            h,
            emptyHeaderCounter
          );
          // console.log("header", normalizedHeader);
          if (normalizedHeader.wasEmpty) emptyHeaderCounter++;
          return normalizedHeader.header;
        },
        skipEmptyLines: "greedy", //Greedy ignores empty lines even after parsing
        dynamicTyping: true,
      });

      // console.log("parsed", parsed);

      // Remove header row from CSV data
      // const data = parsed.data.slice(1);

      const parsedNormalizedReadings = parsed.data.map((row: any) => {
        //Custom parsing depending on the fields of the selected rows

        //device_id
        const device_id = row[parsed.meta.fields![templateData.device_id!]];

        //Billing Date Time
        let billing_date_time =
          row[parsed.meta.fields![templateData.billing_date_time!]];

        let parsedDate = null;
        if (billing_date_time?.includes("Data di fatturazione:")) {
          parsedDate = parse(
            billing_date_time.replace("Data di fatturazione:", "").trim(),
            "dd.MM.yyyy",
            new Date()
          );
        } else {
          let dateFound = false;
          for (const format of possibleFormats) {
            console.log("data originale", billing_date_time);
            parsedDate = parse(billing_date_time, format, new Date());
            if (isValid(parsedDate)) {
              dateFound = true;
              console.log("parsed correctly");
              break;
            }
          }
          if (!dateFound) {
            console.log("date not found");
            parsedDate = null;
          }
        }

        console.log("afterparse", parsedDate);

        //billing_value
        const billing_value =
          row[parsed.meta.fields![templateData.billing_value_column!]];

        //billing_value_extra
        const billing_value_extra =
          row[parsed.meta.fields![templateData.billing_value_extra_column!]];

        //Returning the final record
        return {
          device_id,
          parsedDate,
          billing_value,
          billing_value_extra,
        };
      });
```